# How to configure Telelogic Synergy so that the default type for "unknown" file is binary rather than ascii?

Tags: version-control, configuration, file-type, cm-synergy

if I am not wrong, Telelogic Synergy mapped new files to a type depending of their extensions.

If the extension is unknown, the file is by default declare as a base type ascii.

Is it possible to make sure that "unknown" file type end up as binary rather than ascii ?

Thanks,

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

According to the Synergy manual (Migration Rules chapter) you should do one of the following:

• Add rules mapping binary archive file names to a non-ascii type, such as binary 
(which is the usual way).

• Manually map the binary archive files to a non-ascii type for items selected from the 
Preview Results list.

• Check the Preview results before performing the load to ensure that the types are 
correct.